# PowerShell history: how do you prevent duplicate commands?

Tags: command-line, powershell, history

**Background:**

PowerShell history is a lot more useful to me now that I have a way to save history across sessions.

```sh
# Run this every time right before you exit PowerShell
get-history -Count $MaximumHistoryCount | export-clixml $IniFileCmdHistory;
```

Now, I am trying to prevent PowerShell from saving duplicate commands to my history.

I tried using `Get-Unique`, but that doesn't work since *every* command in the history is "unique", because each one has a different ID number.

Comment: There's `Set-PSReadlineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Get-Unique also requires a sorted list and I assume you probably want to
preserve execution order. Try this instead

```sh
Get-History -Count 32767 | Group CommandLine | Foreach {$_.Group[0]} |
Export-Clixml "$home\pshist.xml"
```

This approach uses the Group-Object cmdlet to create unique buckets of commands
and then the Foreach-Object block just grabs the first item in each bucket.

BTW if you want all commands saved to a history file I would use the limit value
- 32767 - unless that is what you set $MaximumHistoryCount to.

BTW if you want to automatically save this on exit you can do this on 2.0 like
so

```sh
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting {
  Get-History -Count 32767 | Group CommandLine |
  Foreach {$_.Group[0]} | Export-CliXml "$home\pshist.xml" } -SupportEvent
```

Then to restore upon load all you need is

```sh
Import-CliXml "$home\pshist.xml" | Add-History
```

Comment: hmm ... thanks for the post, but did you leave out the part where assign to $hist?

Comment: Sorry, I was just picking a variable name other than $IniFileCmdHistory in order to avoid the dreaded horizontal scrollbar.  :-)

Comment: What about just `Get-History | Select -Unique`? That works for me here at least and avoids the grouping and foreach (where I had to look twice before understanding what you do there :-))

Comment: That's what I originally had put as my answer but the resulting object isn't a full fledged HistoryInfo object so when you try to rehydrate the history from file using "Import-Clixml <path> | Add-History" you get an error.

Comment: @Keith does this command prevent duplicate commands, or remove them? In other words, when I type ls 80 times, do I have to press up arrow 80 times to return to the command before "ls"? Or just twice?

Comment: It doesn't prevent duplicate commands in the current session but it will eliminate them from the previous session's commands that you load into a new session.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip, Keith. I would make one minor tweak, though: `if (Test-path $MyHistoryFile) { Import-CliXml $MyHistoryFile | Add-History }` That avoids the error message that will occur the first time one starts PowerShell after editing one's profile.

Comment: didn't work for me this way. I found this link which did the trick for me: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/06/17/giving-powershell-a-persistent-history-of-commands

Answer (score 11):

The following command works for PowerShell in Windows 10 (tested in v.1803). The option is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption).

```
Set-PSReadLineOption –HistoryNoDuplicates:$True
```

In practice, calling PowerShell with the following command (e.g. saved in a shortcut) opens PowerShell with a history without duplicates

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-PSReadLineOption –HistoryNoDuplicates:$True
```

Comment: Simply putting `Set-PSReadLineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates` in my `$PROFILE` works now.  Not sure if it was a problem with earlier versions or not.

Comment: Using a PowerShell profile also works. It requires [creating it](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/) and changing the default [execution policy](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170) which prevents running scripts.

Comment: `-HistoryNoDuplicates` works  but if you have multiple flags (weirdly?) the order matters and only works when it comes last. for example this works
`Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource HistoryAndPlugin -PredictionViewStyle ListView –HistoryNoDuplicates`
but this won't
`Set-PSReadLineOption –HistoryNoDuplicates -PredictionSource HistoryAndPlugin -PredictionViewStyle ListView`

Answer (score 3):

Not directly related to duplicates, but similarly useful, this `AddToHistoryHandler` script block in my `$PROFILE` keeps short and simple commands out of my history:

```
$addToHistoryHandler = {
    Param([string]$line)
    if ($line.Length -le 3) {
        return $false
    }
    if (@("exit","dir","ls","pwd","cd ..").Contains($line.ToLowerInvariant())) {
        return $false
    }
    return $true
}
Set-PSReadlineOption -AddToHistoryHandler $addToHistoryHandler
```

Comment: Helpful. Thanks. 