# Accessing PowerShell history with up-arrow

Tags: windows, powershell

I recently switched to powershell since my Cygwin bash started giving me senseless compilation errors when using maven. I've found how to save and restore my command history in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259723/is-there-a-windows-shell-tool-can-keep-history), which seems to work (using "History" will show the recent commands after a clean start).

What I can't seem to do is access this history with the up arrow like you would if the command was used in the current session.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you exiting the PS session and re-starting it all over again ?

Comment: I am afraid what you are asking doesn't exist. If you do not exit the session, then the up arrow functionality comes out of the box like in _cmd.exe_ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. There is no API for accessing a console program's history.

Comment: Indeed it seems it's not possible. oh well, I guess I'll go debug Cygwin then, or just make a batch to wrap the commands, as typing 3 line commands every time I boot is a total pain.

Comment: You can make a PowerShell function, too. You can put it in your profile to have it every time you start PS.

Comment: As of October 2013, this is now finally possible using the wonderful PSReadLine module: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine (see alternative answer)

Answer (score 23):

I would suggest killing this old habit (I know, they die hard) and using PowerShell specific feature that is build for that. It's in fact pretty awesome. This is #*[tab], there are 2 options here (tab in brackets ([tab]) means that the tab button should be pressed):

```
#pattern_from_command[tab]
```

-> Powershell cycles through all commands in history that contain "pattern_from_command".

-> EG: In Powershell: type #echo, press tab -> Powershell cycles through all commands in history that contain "echo" (of course if any).

```
#<id>[tab]
```

-> Powershell completes command with id <id>.

-> EG: In Powershell: type #3, press tab -> Powershell writes the third (3) command in history to command line (though not executing it directly, just press enter to execute it).

I know it's not the same as you would do in bash, but I think it's worth trying and getting used to.

**EDIT**: It appears that recent versions of PSReadLine removed that functionality. You are better off with functionality in PSReadLine anyways, but if you want to give it a try in regular console, and it doesn't work - just

```
Remove-Module -Name PSReadLine
```

Functionality still works in any host that doesn't load PSReadLine by default (e.g. PowerShell ISE).

Comment: Technically this is a workaround to my problem, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: but need more key press and it also not very convenient.

Comment: holycrap! holy crap. hooly crap. This is awesome. How did I not know about this.

Comment: Thought it would be nice to mention `h[enter]` shows your history

Comment: Sorry, I give you a downvote for the sentence " would suggest killing this old habit (I know, they die hard)". Your tip with the history search is very helpful, but it does extend and not replace "arrow up". I.e. if you are working on a command and you are adding more options, you don't want to search again and again.

Comment: THIS NO LONGER WORKS.

Comment: I'm using powershell 7.3.7 on mac and it's not working for me.

Answer (score 9):

Like say [@jhclark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758067/jhclark) it is now possible

You have all the documentation for installation in the official GitHub : https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine

You will have to follow the whole tutorial well and pay attention to:

- remove `-AllowPrerelease` arg if you have error
- add this line `Import-Module 'PSReadLine'` in your profile `code $PROFILE` for example to open your profile conf with vscode
- Close all shell after you install `PSReadLine` if you want all work fine

Launch this two lines if you want the fleche to search in the history like on Linux because that is, I think, what most people are looking for:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward
```

by default are the key combinations `F8` and `SHIFT + F8` which are configured by default

You can see the conf with that :

```
Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler
```

Comment: I have to delete the shipped `PSReadline` manually to make  it work.

Answer (score 7):

As of October 2013, this is now possible using the wonderful PSReadline module:  http://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

You'll still need to save your history when your powershell session exits and load it in your profile.ps1 prior to loading PSReadline (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156792.aspx). You can register a hook to save your history when PowerShell exists using a hook like this: [Powershell profile "on exit" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436510/powershell-profile-on-exit-event). Unlike vanilla PowerShell, PSReadLine allows the up/down keys to access this history buffer.

Comment: I don't see this feature in PSReadline. It does add a current session history pattern search function to the up/down arrows, but it does not join the saved history and current session history to a single queue via arrow keys, unless it is not explained but rather is left as a scripting exercise. Which is what microsoft has done.

Comment: Charles: True, loading the history isn't done yet by PSReadline. Without PSReadline, even if you load the history, it's loaded into a separate buffer than the one used by the up/down arrows -- that is, if you load your history traditional PowerShell can't access it using up/down. With PSReadline, if you load your history, it *is* available using the up/down arrows. So, assuming you do this 2 line "scripting exercise", PSReadline does allow you to get this behavior. Answer modified to clarify.

Comment: As of summer 2014, history management is now also supported in PSReadline.

Comment: @jhclark, how did you get this to work?  I've tried loading the history before importing PSReadline but it is still not available using the up/down arrows.

Comment: Update:  figured it out.  you have to add the following lines to the profile script, and remove all of the commands with Get/Add-History `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key UpArrow -Function HistorySearchBackward
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key DownArrow -Function HistorySearchForward
Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySavePath drive:\path\to\file.txt`

Comment: @MonaLisaOverdrive  Can you provide the entire profile script?  It's still not working for me.   :(