# Windows PowerShell persistent history

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface

I found this excellent looking method of [persisting history in Windows PowerShell](http://lopsa.org/content/persistent-history-powershell).

```sh
# Persistent History
# Save last 200 history items on exit
$MaximumHistoryCount = 200
$historyPath = Join-Path (split-path $profile) history.clixml

# Hook powershell's exiting event & hide the registration with -supportevent (from nivot.org)
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    Get-History -Count $MaximumHistoryCount | Export-Clixml (Join-Path (split-path $profile) history.clixml)
}

# Load previous history, if it exists
if ((Test-Path $historyPath)) {
    Import-Clixml $historyPath | ? {$count++;$true} | Add-History
    Write-Host -Fore Green "`nLoaded $count history item(s).`n"
}

# Aliases and functions to make it useful
New-Alias -Name i -Value Invoke-History -Description "Invoke history alias"
Rename-Item Alias:\h original_h -Force
function h { Get-History -c  $MaximumHistoryCount }
function hg($arg) { Get-History -c $MaximumHistoryCount | out-string -stream | select-string $arg }
```

However, when I paste this into my $PROFILE and restart PowerShell I get the
following error:

```
Register-EngineEvent : Missing an argument for parameter 'Action'. Specify a parameter of type
'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' and try again.
At D:\path\to\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:20 char:73
+ Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action
+                                                                         ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Register-EngineEvent], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterEngineEventCommand
```

Comment: FYI, PowerShell v3 fixes a number of issues you're trying to work around.  $MaximumHistoryCount is 4096 by default and by default Get-History returns all items.

Comment: > $PSVersionTable.PSVersion Major = 3, Minor = 0, Build = -1, Revision = -1

Comment: Cool. Then you can skip modifying $MaximumHistoryCount and Get-History will return all history for you (well, up to 4096 items).  Unless that is, you want to limit how much is saved.  :-)

Comment: Here's [my history export/import](https://github.com/aarismendi/ps-scripts/blob/master/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) feel free to steal :P

Comment: @AndyArismendi you don't have a license stated anywhere, so I can't use it

Comment: Related: For all PowerShell history of all time, see *[How can I see the command history across all PowerShell sessions in Windows Server 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104043)*

Answer (score 10):

Very related to this question is "How do I access my history using the up/down arrows?" The [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) module solves this:

```
Install-Package PSReadLine
```

Then add:

```
Import-Module PSReadLine
```

To your `$profile`.

Comment: Note that PSReadLine now ships with Windows 10. :)

Comment: Windows PowerShell ISE has history by pressing `up` and `down` by default.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as a combination of the topicstarter's code and a slightly changed answer by Steven Penny, this is the full piece of code which is working for me

```
################# Persistent History ############
# Save last 200 history items on exit
$MaximumHistoryCount = 200    
$historyPath = Join-Path (split-path $profile) history.clixml

# Hook powershell's exiting event & hide the registration with -supportevent (from nivot.org)
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
      Get-History | Export-Clixml $historyPath
}.GetNewClosure()

# Load previous history, if it exists
if ((Test-Path $historyPath)) {
    Import-Clixml $historyPath | ? {$count++;$true} | Add-History
    Write-Host -Fore Green "`nLoaded $count history item(s).`n"
}

# Aliases and functions to make it useful
New-Alias -Name i -Value Invoke-History -Description "Invoke history alias"
Rename-Item Alias:\h original_h -Force
function h { Get-History -c  $MaximumHistoryCount }
function hg($arg) { Get-History -c $MaximumHistoryCount | out-string -stream | select-string $arg }
```

Comment: This works great (get-history works) but up/down doesn't move through the history items - any idea how to make that work?

Comment: Import PsReadline to do up/down move thru history.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used to use when I persisted my history:

```sh
$historyPath = Join-Path (split-path $profile) "history-$(Get-Date -f o).clixml"
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    Get-History | Export-Clixml $historyPath
}.GetNewClosure()
```

The `GetNewClosure()` is used to capture the `$historyPath` variable IIRC.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Is that the whole code that you used? Is the blog post I'm following doing something unecessary with the section under # Load previous history, if it exists?

Comment: It's up to you but over time that history is going to get awfully large. I prefer to have a simple mechanism to search my persisted history.

Comment: Cool. I'll test it out tomorrow when I'm back in the office. Thanks!

Comment: So I added the text exactly as you have it to my $PROFILE file and when I exit and restart PowerShell I still have no history access when I hit F7 or F8

Comment: And all I need to add is the four lines you've posted here - or do I need to do something else as well? Cheers!

Comment: That's it.  When you exit PowerShell (V3 in my case), you should see a history-xxxx.clixml file in your `$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` directory.

Comment: I might also point out that Keith's earlier answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1439174/115690) is better, because it prunes duplicates. :-)